# ionic 3 QR Scanner is not working for PWA

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I want to use a QR Code Scanner in my ionic PWA which is deployed in ionic native app and calling via inappbrowser inside ionic native app.

While Using QR Scanner Plugin i'm getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some ionic native plugins don't support browser platform, so you need to check the plugins that you are using if it supports browser platform. Looking on the qr scanner plugin documentation, they indicated that they are supporting browser platform. 
You can try to run the code below so you need to specify which platform to run.

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

if the plugin doesn't work, try checking for other plugins that supports browser platform or search for an HTML5 version, for example the plugin below:

> https://github.com/code-kotis/qr-code-scanner

Comment: i have tried html5 version and js libraries but it's not working when calling inside an app and working only in browser